# Change data export download link label

Tags: 8, views, theming

I want to change the label shown to export csv file download link that generated with data export of a view. I didn't get any setting to change the label of download link - download full list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download button is actually rendered from a twig template found at `/views_data_export/templates/export-icon.html.twig`. This means that you can override it in your theme by copying that file to `/themes/YOUR_THEME/templates/export-icon.html.twig` and modifying it to what you need.

You can of course put that twig file into any subdir of `/templates/` that makes sense to you - e.g. `/templates/views_data_export/export-icon.html.twig` will work as well.